# none of the w3schools ajax examples work in firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox

None of the ajax examples on the w3schools site seems to work for me in firefox 3.0.19

For example: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

Any ideas how this should be fixed? I've got the same problem on my site...

Comment: I suggest you update your Firefox ASAP.  3.0.x is not supported with security fixes anymore, so you're running a browser with known unpatched security holes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start fixing it by [avoiding w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com) altogether. When I read "for IE6, IE5" in the example source I had a shudder.

As an AJAX beginner it would be easier and simpler if you used jQuery or some other JS library's AJAX facilities. Googling for "jquery ajax tutorial" should give you more than enough to get started.

A final aside: upgrading FF to 3.6 or 4 would also not be a bad idea.

Comment: -1 This is at best a comment, not an answer. I _have_ to code Ajax for IE6, because my client is one of the big corporates whose IT department refuses to upgrade. Similarly, with jQuery, although I love to use it whenever I can one particular client will not allow it so I had to learn AJAX the old-fashioned way, and W3Schools was very helpful with this.

Comment: @Blowski: Your having to code for IE6 due to business requirements and W3schools' *freely made decision* to provide examples coded for IE6 in the year 2011 are two quite different things. And did you follow the link I provided (which is also put up by many people here on SO every little while)? As for the -1, I can live with it -- although "ditch W3schools, it's probably a bad example that causes you problems" is definitely meant as an answer.

Comment: As long as people are still using IE6, advice on how to code for it is still necessary. I've seen the link before and think it's one of those pages that experienced people read when they've forgotten what it's like to be a novice. There was a time when neither of us knew what `margin-top` or `block level elements` referred to, and reading the 'alternative descriptions' on that site would have left me none the wiser.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Javascript is enabled in your "firefox" browser.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Firebug add-on and look in the console.

My guess is that you have something like NoScript installed, or the Web Developer toolbar with Disable JavaScript set to true. I have done this lots of times :)